# Unable to browse to folder on SSRS 2012 through report url

Tags: ssrs, ssrs-2012

I have installed SSRS 2012 in native mode on windows server 2012 r2 and deployed reports to the server successfully. I am having difficult browsing to any report folder through the report URL. I can browse to the report server home folder using the following URL:

http://192.168.8.1/My_ReportServer

From this URL I can then successfully navigate through the folders and run the reports correctly.

If I try to navigate directly to one of the folders in the home folder through URL.

http://192.168.8.1/My_ReportServer/test

I receive the following message:

### Server Error in '/My_ReportServerApplication.

The resource cannot be found. 
  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /My_ReportServer/test.

Does anyone know the cause of this problem? or point me in the right direction?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days of trying different things. I have found the resolution. To browse to the folder for some reason I have to use the path: http://192.168.8.1/My_ReportServer/test?/test

Answer (score 0):

You will have to call /pages/folder.aspx with an ItemPath parameter as absolute path /Test which url encoded will look like this.

> http://192.168.8.1/My_ReportSever/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=%2fTest

You can of course always copy/paste the url when you browse the server.

Comment: Thanks for responding. After two days of trying different things. I have found the resolution. To browse to the folder for some reason I have to use the path: http://192.168.8.1/My_ReportServer/test?/test